# How to include a script file whose name is read from the INI file?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I would like to include a script file whose name will be read from an INI file. I've tried this:

```
#include <subfolder\{#ReadIni(SourcePath + "File.ini", "Section", "Key", "")}.iss>
```

but the compilation fails on this error:

> File not found: "subfolder\{#ReadIni(SourcePath + "File.ini",
>   "Section", "Key", "")}.iss"

How can I include a script file whose name is read from the INI file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot inline function result that way. Do it like this:

```
#include "subfolder\" + ReadIni(SourcePath + "File.ini", "Section", "Key", "") + ".iss"
```